# How can an answer that is not downvoted receive a delete-vote?

Tags: discussion, support, deletion

My answer of this question :

[Partition with identical parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213545/partition-with-identical-parts/3213547#3213547)

was upvoted , but received also a delete vote.

> How can an answer that is not downvoted, receive a delete-vote ?

Comment: Here is the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3213547/timeline) of the linked answer. Based on the timeline it seems that the deleted vote came from the low quality review and that the delete vote came before the upvote. (Although the timeline does not show the exact time of votes - just a daily summary.)

Answer (score 3):

As [Martin Sleziak commented](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30206/how-can-an-answer-that-is-not-downvoted-receive-a-delete-vote#comment130341_30206), the delete vote came from [a trusted user](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) on the Low Quality Post review queue. Trusted users can vote to delete **zero**-scored answers from the review queue directly.

As explained by Shog9 from [Why I'm casting delete votes in the Low Quality review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230873/241919),

> Review gives you a bit of a boost by allowing you to vote to delete 0-scored answers. This is done just to save you the step of having to down-vote them first and then vote to delete.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have experienced this many times on a site I had been a trusted user by voting to delete 0-scored answers from the LQP review queue, then downvoting them from outside the queue and seeing they already had my delete vote.